# How to communicate with the delegate in a custom class's init method in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I spent much time to get a better understanding in delegation in Objective-C. I got it working for most cases, but there is a problem in a specific case, which I find difficult to understand. Let me explain what I am trying to do:

I have a custom view called `GridLayoutView`, which is subclass of `UIView`. I also have a view controller `SomeViewController`, which is the delegate of `GridLayoutView`.

I have a custom `initWithFrame` method, and I am conditionally calling another initialization method `baseInit`. That method calls a delegate method at some time. Here is some code from `GridLayoutView`:

```
//
// Delegator
// GridLayoutView.m
//

@implementation GridLayoutView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
       numberOfRows:(NSUInteger)rows
       numberOfCols:(NSUInteger)cols
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.numberOfRows = rows;
        self.numberOfCols = cols;
        self.numberOfCells = rows * cols;

        if (self.numberOfCells > 0) [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)baseInit
{
    // do some more initialization stuff here
    // ...

    // then call a delegate method
    [self.delegate someMethod:someObj];

    // However, this method is not called because self.delegate is nil
}
```

and some code from `SomeViewController`:

```
//
// Delegate
// SomeViewController.m
//

@implementation SomeViewController

// ...

    // in some method
    self.gridLayoutView = [[GridLayoutView alloc] initWithFrame:gridLayoutFrame
                                                   numberOfRows:rowsCount
                                                   numberOfCols:colsCount];
    self.gridLayoutView.delegate = self;

// ...
```

The delegate method never gets called within `baseInit`, because the delegate is `nil` at that time and it gets set after `initWithFrame` and `baseInit` methods are done. I have confirmed this.

I sense that there is something wrong in my workflow of delegation. I have a solution but I don't think it is the best way to go. The solution is basically passing the `SomeViewController` instance to the delegator by modifying the `initWithFrame` method such as:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
       numberOfRows:(NSUInteger)rows
       numberOfCols:(NSUInteger)cols
           delegate:(id<GridLayoutViewDelegate>)aDelegate
```

This approach works, but I am uncomfortable due to passing `SomeViewController` to `GridLayoutView` in its `initWithRect`. I am wondering if this is a good way to go with delegation or is there a better approach? I would be very grateful if someone can clear this for me.

Comment: Why do you even want to call a delegate method from within `-init`? That seems crazy.

Comment: Well, the main reason is that I am loading a lot of views in `-init` and I wanted to send the percentage of loading to the delegate so that it can update a progress indicator.

Comment: But that was unsuccessful, because the progress indicator is either zero or 100%. I think that is because all UI operations take place in the main thread and the app freezes until all elements are loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, there aren't many options here.

1. Modifying your initializer (as you suggested) to pass in the delegate. There is nothing wrong with that, don't know why you don't like it.
2. Remove the dependency on the delegate during initialization and instead, send whatever delegate message is appropriate when the delegate property is set by overriding the setter:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<GridLayoutViewDelegate>)aDelegate
{
    _delegate = aDelegate;
    // send whatever message makes sense to the delegate
    [_delegate someMethod:object];
}
```

**EDIT - noticed your comment**

Your initialization method should not take any significant amount of time. It's unclear what you mean by 'loading views'. If you simply mean creating and adding subviews to a view then that is fast and there should be no need to communicate progress to a delegate (which you can't do anyway b/c the initialization is on the main thread and UI won't update until all of init is complete).

If you mean loading data that takes a long time, you should disconnect that from initialization and load the data in a background operation, sending progress messages to a delegate.

Comment: Just as you mentioned, I am creating `UILabel` and `UITextField` views and adding them as subviews to `GridLayoutView`. There is no data loading. But it still takes a long time, because `GridLayoutView` is subview of a `UIScrollView` and the number of UI elements can be a lot. Currently, I don't have a way to draw only the ones that are visible on the screen (maybe a few more rows and columns) and reuse them as the user scrolls. I am trying to work this out.

Comment: Actually, data loading method is in `SomeViewController` and it is called after all subviews are added. Now I noticed that as you suggested, adding subviews is pretty quick and the freezing is due to data loading. Can I set the `UITextField`'s `text` property in another thread other than the main?

Comment: All UI operations need to happen on the main thread. You need to load your data on a background thread into a relevant data structure. This could be an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` if you have simple needs. When the data is loaded you then call a method on the main thread which sets `textField.text` to the appropriate value from the loaded data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your comments. I don't need the progress indicator and even the delegate it seems.

Answer (score 0):

i would implement the setDelegate function and then call 
 [self someMethod:someObj]; from there

Comment: Well in my case, the `someMethod` that I am calling have variables related to initialization so it doesn't make sense to call it in `setDelegate`.